Google Sign-In Error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10) without Firebase
I'm trying to implement Google Sign-In in my Android app without using Firebase.
I've already set the SHA-1 key in the Google Cloud Console for my package name, but I keep encountering the following error:

I/flutter (23285): Google Sign-In Error: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

I already:

Generated the SHA-1 key from my upload keystore.
Added the SHA-1 fingerprint to my OAuth 2.0 client ID in the Google Cloud Console.
Configured my package name in the Google Cloud Console to match my app's package name.

Is there something I'm missing or any additional steps I need to follow to resolve this issue?

Recheck dependencies added in build.gradle files and AndroidManifest.xml with meta-data tag. Also check SHA-1 fingerprint and package name are correctly set in the Google Cloud Console.
